# Fallo de sintaxis en llamada PHP a una Select

Tags: php, sql

Tengo esta select para que muestre entre paréntesis unos datos, pero creo que tiene un fallo de sintaxis:

```
<select class="form-control" name="compania1" id="compania1">
       <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('compania') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('compania') : ''; ?> </option>
               <?php
                    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=final', 'root', '');
                    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                    $pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';SET lc_messages = 'es_ES'");
                    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
                    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select * from compania order by acronimo');
                    $stmt->execute();
                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo '<option name="' .
                    ($row['acronimo']) . '">' .($row['acronimo'] . '(' .$row['nombre'] . ')') . '</option>';
   }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Qué dice el error que te sale?

Comment: no marca error, pero es como si no cojiera el dato

Comment: Creo que lo que tienes que hacer es especificar las columnas dentro de el select, para que tu fetch te regrese los datos que ocupas en tu ciclo.

Comment: si, pero lo que tengo dudas es si he recorrido bien las columnas, solo tiene dos "acrónimo y nombre"

Comment: Haz un `print_r( $row )` dentro del `while ( $row`  para ver si la base de datos te está cogiendo correctamente los valores.